# Word for something so familiar or ubiquitous that it goes unnoticed?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Like water to a fish, this thing is not entirely imperceptible but it is rarely noted, if at all.

Comment: Ubiquity is not subject to degree.

Comment: I should reword the question: 'ubiquitous or so familiar ...'

Comment: Good luck with that battle. Oxford dictionaries: "These days, the programme is so popular and so ubiquitous, that I just tend to keep quiet." http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ubiquitous

Comment: Might it be the Higgs Boson?

Comment: I've used phrases like "What is it like for a fish to swim in water?"  I doubt that there is a good single word.  (The Germans probably have something, though.)

Comment: "Gestalt", perhaps?

Comment: *presumed* is a word

Comment: @JimReynolds Be aware that Oxford Dictionaries is simply a dictionary which has Oxford as part of its name. It is not the highly prestigious Oxford English Dictionary. The latter will clearly confirm that *ubiquitous* means being everywhere at the same time. God is said to be *ubiquitous*. You cannot possibly have degrees of ubiquity any more than you can have degrees of immortality.

Answer (score 2):

simile or metaphor might work best.  "just part of the scenery", "as familiar as the furniture".  Or you could say that something "disappeared into the background".

Answer (score 1):

You can consider ***overfamiliar***.

> - common or repeated to the point of being unnoticed or annoying
> - *(Used with “with”)* so acquainted with something, that one doesn't notice it, or is annoyed by it
>
> [[*Wiktionary*]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overfamiliar)

As you can see from the definition, an *overfamiliar* thing/person can be either unnoticed or annoying. Scientifically, this phenomenon is related to *subconscious mind* and even *inattentional blindness*. For example, breathing is controlled by subconscious most of the time unless you pay attention to it. *Inattentional blindness* suggests that even the most common things go unnoticed if you do not pay close attention to them.

---

Fish/water example is a bit controversial though. For example, there is a question circling around the internet: "Do fish know they are wet?". It can also be asked as "Do fish know they are in water?". This is related to the intelligence level of fish. They do not comprehend concepts as humans do. Their perception and memory systems are different. They might just know that they survive in the environment that they are in.

Although, there are also intelligent species that live in the water. For example, dolphins. They are mammals and they can stay out of water for a while. They also rise to the surface to breathe. They might be perceiving different environments and they might know the difference between wet and dry.

Answer (score 1):

The apparent oxymoron:

> [Hidden in plain sight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hide_in_plain_sight)

[which only appeared in about 1990](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hidden+in+plain+sight%2Chiding+in+plain+sight&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3), might be used to convey this idea in some circumstances. (The poster does not provide an example sentence for me to judge the appropriateness in his context.)

The Wiktionary definition linked above — “to be unnoticeable by staying visible” — reflects its employment in crime fiction and the like. However, it is evident from several books that incorporate the term in their titles, that it is also used in a more metaphorical or abstract manner. e.g.

> “It was right there, *hidden in plain sight* among the syllables and
> syntax of a few words of advice from the apostle Peter.”
> *Hidden in Plain Sight: The Secret of More, Mark Buchan (2012)*

> “Symbology: Hidden In Plain Sight” brings to the curious mind a better understanding of myths and folklore and the symbolism that accompanies them.”
> *Symbology: Hidden In Plain Sight. The Secret Life of Symbols, Michelle Snyder (2014)*

> “Hidden in Plain Sight. The Simple Link Between Relativity and Quantum Mechanics”
> *Andrew H. Thomas (2012)*

I leave the reader to choose between quantum mechanics, symbolism and St Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm unable to access a single word which includes the cause of the imperceptions, single words which are *suggestive* of your question:

Medium, i.e., ‘these organisms were growing in their natural medium’;
Ambient: completely enveloping; 
Elemental, in the sense of being so fundamental as to be imperceptible; 
Milieu: the surrounding environment or setting.